# Android centering an textview next to a imageview

Tags: android-layout, centering

I have an imageview and i want to put in the right a textview, but that will stay centered verticaly, so I can make my custom listview.

This photo can explain better:
[image]

My code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="top" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:src="@drawable/icon1" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageView1"
        android:text="Large Text"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set your TextView's attribute

```
android:layout_centerVertical="true"
```

It would be even better if you set your image as a compound drawable inside the TextView (to the left of it):

```
android:drawableLeft="@drawable/icon1"
android:drawablePadding="8dp"
```

The two lines above are in the TextView definition and completely replace your ImageView.
This is a best practice and increases the overall performance, by flattening your layout hierarchy.

And remove the `android:gravity="top"` attribute in the parent.
Also, to make this the item row of a ListView, this `android:layout_height="match_parent"` should be `android:layout_height="wrap_content"`

Comment: If I put android:centerVertical="true" at the textview everything looks the same..

Comment: Sure... I didn't notice the `gravity="top"` in the parent! And there's also another error in the parent: `android:layout_height="match_parent"` should be `android:layout_height="wrap_content"`

Comment: I've removed the android gravity line, and added android:centerVertical="true" to my textbox, still same thing in my graphical layout

Comment: The problem was that i had to write  android:layout_centerVertical="true" not android:centerVertical, now it works.

Comment: Sorry, my bad... I did it by memory. - It seems I tend to forget **layout_** ;)

Comment: `android:layout_centerVertical="true" ` did not work for me, but `android:gravity="center_vertical"` did.

Comment: @Tom You aren't using a **RelativeLayout**. This one `android:layout_centerVertical="true"` is **specific** to RelativeLayouts.